# JSON.parse() results in Error: A cross-origin error was thrown

Tags: reactjs, json

I have looked at all the other questions on StackOverflow regarding this and none of them have an answer. First I do:
`let jsonString = JSON.stringify(chat)`
and the `jsonString` object looks like this:

```
{"chatId":1,
"chats":[
{"user":"Travis","content":"Hello","timestamp":"1629879452051","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},
{"user":"Michael","content":"What's up","timestamp":"1629879452052","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},
{"user":"Travis","content":"How's it going","timestamp":"1629879452053","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},
{"user":"Michael","content":"Good hbu","timestamp":"1629879452054","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},
{"user":"Travis","content":"Good wyd","timestamp":"1629879452055","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},{"user":"Michael","content":"Coding","timestamp":"1629879452056","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]},{"user":"Travis","content":"Cool","timestamp":"1629879452057","coordinates":[-105.25,40.0024,105.5]}
]
}
```

Which is valid JSON. The next line of code is:
`let test = JSON.parse(jsonString)`

As soon as I add this code, the app crashes and reports the error but if I remove that line it works fine. If this is valid JSON why is my app reporting this error?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is not `JSON.parse`. Please post the code that causes the error.

Comment: Also, are you sure that `JSON.parse` is actually throwing an `Error` - or is it parsing an actual error message?

Comment: @Dai Updated, forgot to include it.

Comment: @Dai When I add that line of code, the error message shows up

Comment: Have you used your step-through debugger? If not, **why not?**

Comment: @Dai what is a step through debugger?

Comment: **\*sigh\***... read this: https://raygun.com/blog/react-debugging-guide/